# jquery find fails with specific nodes name

Tags: jquery, xml, find

Im trying to parse string, with xml structure inside, with jQuery.find()

```
xml = "<xml><nodes>....</nodes></xml>";
$(xml).find('some_node_name').each(function(){
// do something
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nSfX7/9/

but...

1. if i start my xml string with a space, find fail.
2. If the name of one node is "template" find wont find anythings inside this node....

In other words, 
with this xml, jquery.find('name') fail:

```
xml = "<xml>
 <template>
   <node name='x'/>
   <node name='y'/>
 </template>
</xml>"
```

but if i change the name of the node from **template** to **templates** or **templatee** or any other words find dont' fail...:

```
xml = "<xml>
 <templates>
   <node name='x'/>
   <node name='y'/>
 </templates>
</xml>"
```

Someone have the same issue & can help me or tell me why jquery have this behaviour?

Tks@all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the html parser is causing the problem, *but why? not sure need to check the parser doc*

Since you are really dealing with xml contents use $.parseXML() instead of using html parser like

```
var doc = $.parseXML(xml);
$(doc).find('item').each(function() {
    $('#out').append('found ITEM :' + $(this).attr('name') + "<br/>" );
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g737q/)